# How to kill a process that says "Operation not permitted" when attempted?

Tags: sudo, kill

I have a process I would like to kill:

```
computer@ubuntu:~$ ps aux | grep socat
root      2092  0.0  0.0   5564  1528 pts/1    T    14:37   0:00 sudo socat TCP:xxx.17.29.152:54321 PTY,link=/dev/ttyGPS0,raw,echo=0,mode=666
computer@ubuntu:~$ kill 2092
-bash: kill: (2092) - Operation not permitted   <--------------- How to kill ??
```

Comment: The command you list here is running as root. Have you tried running `sudo kill 2092`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try kill command with with -9 signal if `sudo kill 'pid'` does not work: 
`sudo kill -9 2092`

Comment: I have a process that cannot be killed even with root (i'm running bash as root already). Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: What process are you trying to kill and the error you are receiving?

Comment: It is a stuck iftop and I get a "permission denied". Both iftop and kill are run by root itself. I started iftop from a bash and I can't kill that bash either.

Comment: there are times even kill -9 may not work.. then try sudo kill -9 pid

Comment: I have a process in which I did `sudo kill -9 2091`  and it still gives this message. Why would that be (`os/x high sierra`)

Comment: It seems there are some processes that cannot be killed even like this. I cannot kill `softwareupdated` like this.

Answer (score 20):

That command is running under sudo as root, your kill command must as well:

`sudo kill 2092`